# What is the main difference between TableAdapter and SqlDataAdapter

Tags: c#

we often use SqlDataAdapter but i never use table adapter. is there any difference? please explain. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [TableAdapter overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tthwx%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):

> Users of previous versions of Visual Studio can think of a TableAdapter as a DataAdapter with a built-in connection object and the ability to contain multiple queries. Each query added to a TableAdapter is exposed as a public method that is simply called like any other method or function on an object.

(The same page contains a lot more information which you may find useful.)